# operation LIKE in PL/SQL with string that contain "_" symbol

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

I have to do a simple select query with the LIKE operator but the problem is that the string to be compared with the LIKE operator contains the symbol "_", for example:

- TRY_1245
- POSTM_A422
- PREP_1000X

And in the table on the DB i have:

- TRY_
- POSTM_
- PREP_

How can I make the query work like this? because if I do the simple LIKE "TRY_1235"
the query returns nothing.

Thanks a lot in advance everyone!

Comment: A LIKE pattern longer than the column value will not match anyway.

Comment: You can use a LIKE ESCAPE character. https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B12037_01/server.101/b10759/conditions016.htm

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you want:

```
WHERE 'TRY_1235' LIKE col || '%'
```

The column can be the pattern.

Note that this will match `'TRYST'` because `_` is a wildcard character.  Perhaps the simplest solution is `REGEXP_LIKE()` -- assuming there are no other unusual characters:

```
WHERE REGEXP_LIKE('TRY_12345', '^' || col)
```

Or just escape the `_`:

```
WHERE 'TRY_12345' LIKE REPLACE(col, '_', '\_') || '%'
```